# Breezejs and java

Tags: java, breeze

I am new in breezejs and just have to know whether it supports Java Server like Tomcat or not..

I mean I saw 100's of examples using **Breeze** and **Asp.net** server but didn't saw any example using **Java server**, please shed some light on this;

Comment: BreezeJS supports the OData standard, which has JVM support in odata4j. I'm working on a blog series showing how to work with BreezeJS on *nix & MacOSX. http://kylehodgson.com/2013/01/21/breezejs-tdd-with-mocha-and-phantomjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well this was on the breeze FAQ

**Based on your documentation, it looks like Breeze is hardwired for .NET. You're even using Visual Studio in your samples.**

Yes, our initial launch shows Breeze using Visual Studio with a .NET Entity Framework back-end.

To be clear, Breeze does not require .NET, but this is currently how we have the data provider hooked up through WebAPI. We are planning to support other back-ends and front-ends, as well as show IDEs other than Visual Studio. Your feedback on UserVoice helps us prioritize these features.

Comment: thanks for the information and i am waiting for the release of breezejs with java framework badly....................

Comment: Ankur, we are considering adding a breeze sample using Java on the server and leveraging http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/.  Would this help?

Comment: I'd love to see good tutorials / evidence that Breeze can work well with JVM languages (which should help with Scala, Java, Ruby, Groovy, Clojure), NodeJS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Work is well underway on a Java backend for Breeze, using Hibernate and JAX-RS.  Please check out [breezejs-hibernate](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.java/tree/master/breezejs-hibernate).

The [NorthBreeze](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/java/NorthBreeze) sample is a web application (WAR) that uses the breezejs-hibernate library.  We build it with Maven and deploy it on Tomcat.  It uses Angular for the UI bits.  It's still pretty rough.

Answer (score 1):

Ankur, please add this request to the breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) ( and vote for it). We take these suggestions seriously when determining what features/samples to work on next.